# Remove NEWLINE character in a SSIS Flat File

Tags: ssis

Is there a way to remove newline character from a flat file in SSIS ??... without a Script Task.

CONTEXT: I need to send all the content of a flat file as a single string value.

Comment: Send how? What is the source of the data? Does it have to become a flat file before you remove the newline? How many rows of data are you trying to fix. More context needed. Please click Edit to clarify your question, what your existing package looks like, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to some SQL database, you could try exporting the data of the flat file onto an SQL table in that database. The data would be loaded into multiple rows in SQL. Then all you need to do is to concatenate the data from all the rows.

**TABLE STRUCTURE**

```
DataRow
----
This
is a 
really
good way.
```

**Code to go into as SQL Statement**

```
DECLARE @Data VARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT @Data = COALESCE(@Data + '', '') + DataRow
FROM YourTable
WHERE ISNULL(DataRow, '') <> ''
SELECT @Data
```

Then you can have the above SQL statements inside an `Execute SQL Task` and the output into a result set and map it onto some string variable, which can be used as per your wish.

Answer (score 0):

I opted to write a simple method to read the entire file and write it to a single String variable, which was actually a DTS variable:

```
public String getFileData(FileInfo file)
    {
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@file.FullName);
        return text;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression in the sql query for the column with the new line character

select 
RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ColumnWithNewLineChar,CHAR(9),''), CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),''))) as ColumnWithOutNewLineChar from table

Tab, char(9). Line feed, char(10). Carriage return, char(13)

Above expression removes/replace the new line chars